# Gulp task finishes but never ends

Tags: node.js, gulp, browserify

**NOTE:** [Here is an example repo with the problem](https://github.com/neezer/gulp-browserify-hanging-task).

When I run `./gulp js`, the process works (creates the expected files on the file system), but the task never completes... just hangs indefinitely:

[ss http://zc.d.pr/4C9U/3GG90rpz+](http://zc.d.pr/4C9U/3GG90rpz+)

I figure I'm not returning something somewhere, or invoking a callback correctly, but after hours of tinkering, head-banging, and Googling, I haven't found a solution.

Can someone help me out here?

If it makes a difference, I'm currently using `node v4.1.0`. All other dependencies and versions are in the example repo linked above.

---

**EDIT:** Original inspiration for this gulp recipe came from https://truongtx.me/2015/06/07/gulp-with-browserify-and-watchify-updated/

However, I couldn't get `transform` to work as that author suggested, which led me to https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/1198#issuecomment-89948202

Answer (score 0):

Of course—as it always happens—I think of something new to try just after I post to SO and it appears to work.

[doh http://zc.d.pr/11uMa/5gghjbCx+](http://zc.d.pr/11uMa/5gghjbCx+)

You can see my full changeset here: https://github.com/neezer/gulp-browserify-hanging-task/commit/8156e182c04c2e76c5739e31f5a6e417dda01b70

**TL;DR** Basically I tried the suggestion [in the last comment on the aforementioned issue from my question](http://zc.d.pr/11uMa/5gghjbCx), where I pass the file object itself to `browserify` instead of the file path, and lo-and-behold, the task finishes now.

I don't pretend to know why that fixed the issue, so if anyone would like to explain, I'd love to learn. ;)